# disable textbox2 on fill of textbox2 and viceversa

Tags: javascript

I have 2 textboxes and i have to disable the other textbox on fill of current textbox. i have used javascript for this and my code is as this. plz help me rectifying this.

```js
var debit = document.getElementById('dr'),
  credit = document.getElementById('cr');

function enableToggle(current, other) {
  other.disabled = current.value.replace(/\s+/, '').length > 0 ? true : false;
}
debit.onkeyup = function() {
  enableToggle(this, credit);
}
credit.onkeyup = function() {
  enableToggle(this, debit);
}
```

```html
<input name="debit" id="dr" type="text" onload="function enableToggle(current, other);" />
<input name="credit" id="cr" type="text" />
```

Comment: when i type in first textbox the second is not getting disabled.

Comment: yes its working in code snippet, but why not on my localhost? M so confused

Answer (score 0):

on html you should use something like this

```
onfocus='enableToggle("IdOfCurrent","IdOfOther");'
```

and in script something like what you have

```
function enableToggle(currentId, otherId)
{
var Current = document.getElementById(CurrentId);
var Other = document.getElementById(OtherId);
// Using Other and current here
}
```